# DOUBLE QUOTATION MARKs in XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I read [XML specification](http://as%20also%20listed%20in) and think - but not quite sure - that LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK or RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK are allowed characters in attribute values.

However, I get an error from Saxon XSLT processor (9.9.1-5) *Invalid byte 3 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence*.
The hex editor showed me the sequence E2-80-9C and E2-80-9D, name Unicode code points 0x201C and 0x201D [as also listed here](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128).

I understand that these characters are excluded from XML NameChar, but not from AttValue.

Probably I am wrong and not Saxon. But why?

Comment: Do you have a link to any such file? Does any XML parser you use/try parse such a file as well-formed XML but only in the context of Saxon you get that error? How do you use Saxon exactly when you get that error, from the command line or using some particular Java or .NET code?

Comment: Sorry, don't know from the information provided. If you supply a small document that illustrates the problem, we can investigate. It may be difficult to post the document here on SO because of encoding issues: if you report it as a support issue at saxonica.plan.io then you will be able to upload the actual file there. You are certainly right that these characters are allowed in XML attribute or text node content without any special escaping. If it does turn out to be a bug rather than a user error (which is unlikely, but I've been wrong before...) then we'll obviously need product versions.

Comment: ok - I'll will try to extract an example that shows the problem. However, can you help me understand XML spec: Shall those quote chars be allowed in attributes? They may happen when I export an Enterprise Architect model to XMI.

Comment: Sure, the characters are allowed, see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSTbeT/1 using Saxon 9.

Comment: Can you add details on exactly which Saxon version you use and how you use it exactly when you get that error with the linked file?

Comment: Now that I know that XML is not the problem I have to dig deeper. This problem does not happen if I call Saxon from commandline. Probably there is something to do when calling Saxon from Java.
Saxon-HE version is 9.9.1-5, I will try with -6 as well.

Comment: The Saxon version isn't going to affect anything because Saxon isn't doing the decoding, it's being done by the underlying XML parser. Please show us your Java code that exhibits the failure.

Comment: I tested with a stripped-down java program and found my(!) fault: some lazy handling of CharSet usage.

Some detail: In case of UTF-8 with BOM, the BOM has to be stripped from the input StreamSource. (right?) By handling the conversion from bytes to chars there was a failure.

I may not delete this question as it asks about whether the characters are allowed. And the answer is: Yes, they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution (distilled from comments on the question):

1. Yes, these characters are permitted in XML
2. The error messages appear to be unrelated to the presence of these characters, and caused by some kind of unspecified user error in handling the decoding.

Comment: The cause was some charset failure in a pre-processing of the xml input file. The pre-processing was necessary because some input files come as UTF-8 with BOM. I found no better way than identifying and in case stripping off the first 3 bytes, prior to passing it to Saxon. However, care has to be taken regarding character set.

Comment: Most XML parsers these days accept UTF-8 input with a BOM. Saxon of course passes the input to the XML parser for decoding, so it depends which parser you are using.